# Apache2 alias in virtual host

Tags: alias, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I have multiple virtual host in one server and plan to has some alias setup in one virtualhost.

So I add the

> Alias /foo/ /path/to/foo/

in virtualhost directive,but it has no effect. Request of host1/foo/ will return 404.
But if I add this to /etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf, it works. But the problem is host2 will also share this alias.

Is there a way to make the alias work only for host1?

BTW, I use `apache2ctl -l`, there's no mod_alias.c listed, weird.

Comment: can you post your alias.conf and apache2.conf/httpd.conf and log file to pastie.org?

Comment: what os you are running on?

Comment: Is `/path/to/foo/` an empty directory?  If there's no `index.html` file there (or whatever your `DirectoryIndex` directive is set to) then a 404 is the correct response.  Try putting a file in that directory and then requesting it with something like `http://host1/foo/file.html`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Alias /test /tmp/test
```

Notice that no shashes at the end of paths.
But I don't know the reason of this effect.

Comment: that's the exact one i use at first, but unfortunately it doesn't work. and then i add slash, make a request with host1/test/, still 404. Is your apache's configuration layout also the split version(apache2.conf, mod-enable, mod-available, conf.d,etc)? I know this works for the traditional monolithic configuration such as httpd.conf.

Comment: Have a look if a file "alias.load" is linked. "alias.conf" doesn't load the module.

Comment: the only line in alias.load is: LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so. Given it works if the Alias is put in the alias.conf, i guess the mod_alias is already loaded.

Comment: It's OK. And does it have a link in enabled directory?

Comment: yep :( /****for post length limit***/

Comment: Stange... Try to increase LogLevel in your apache2.conf and examine the logs. Or even show them?

Comment: I remove and purge the apache2 and then reinstall it. Now it works...seems original apache2 is broken. thanks for the reply.

Comment: That's strange... But I'm glad this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The folder /etc/apache2/mods-available/ shows available modules, not installed/enabled ones.
this means mod_alias is NOT enabled on your machine.

maybe there is a folder like mods-enabled. 
create with that folder a link to the file /etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf. after that reload/restart the webserver.

next is wrong (see comments):
<strike>apache2ctl -l should show the module.</strike>

run "httpd -M" to see the current loaded modules -> [httpd command reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httpd.html)

maybe this command doesnt work on your os. every distribution is a bit different.
on gentoo use: "apache2ctl modules"

Comment: there is alias.conf in mod-enabled, and it's a softlink to mod-available. but apache2ctl -l still didn't show. most of the web's tutorial about alias(and other module load configure) is too old (didn't have the split configuration file layout mentioned)

Comment: Your answer seems to be reasonable. But when I run apache2ctl -l, I get:
root@host:~# apache2ctl -l
Compiled in modules:
So this shows only "compiled in" modules
And of course, "alias.load" also requres linking.(on Debian system)

Answer (score 0):

```
BTW, I use apache2ctl -l, there's no mod_alias.c listed, weird.
```

Then that is your problem. If `mod_alias` is not installed, your alias directive will fail. Have that setup & installed & all should work as expected.

Comment: The `-l` option only lists modules that were *compiled* into Apache.  Modules can still be *loaded* separately.  You can list these with the `-M` option.

Comment: Indeed, but if that is the case, the issue of it still not being loaded is in question since that `alias` directive clearly should work.